# How to set up related collection items rather than related posts in Jekyll?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I've successfully implemented **related posts** in my site by using `site.related_posts` with the following Liquid templating:

The code bellow returns 4 posts related by tags on every post page, so far so good, but what's the best approach to achieve something like this for Jekyll collections?

```
{% assign hasSimilar = '' %}

{% for post in site.related_posts %}
 {% assign postHasSimilar = false %}
   {% for tag in post.tags %}
     {% for thisTag in page.tags %}
       {% if postHasSimilar == false and hasSimilar.size < 4 and post != page and tag == thisTag %}
       {% if hasSimilar.size == 0 %}
       {% endif %}

     <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class="entry">
      <div class="entry-media">
      <img src="{{ post.thumbnail | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt="">
      <p class="post-cat">{% for category in post.categories.last %}{{ category }}{% endfor %}</p>
      </div>
      <h6 class="entry-title">{{ post.title | truncatewords: 70, '...' }}</h6>
      <p class="post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%d/%m/%Y" }}</p>{% if post.series %}(Series: {{ post.series }}){% endif %}
     </a>
{% capture hasSimilar %}{{ hasSimilar }}*{% endcapture %}
 {% assign postHasSimilar = true %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
       {% if hasSimilar.size > 0 %}

{% endif %}
```

As per Jekyll's documentation, when you create a collection it becomes available via the `site` Liquid variable, much like `site.pages` and `site.posts`, so in order to create a **related collection items** for my **portfolio** collection I replicated the Liquid logic above and assigned  **site.portfolio** as posts, see:

`{% assign posts = site.portfolio | sort: "tags" %}`

So I set `tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]` on every "project.md" document's front-matter within my `_portfolio` collectionas, as I'd normally do with posts and the liquid logic above returns the related **portfolio collection items**.

Anyway, although I'm not sure if this is the right path to achieve such functionality, it works as intended. I couldn't find any references/ usage for `site.related_posts` when it come to collections.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts regarding this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site.related_posts` are the [ten most recent posts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables).

So, your code is only looking for related in ten posts not all posts.

The following code will looks for tags related items for site.posts or any site.collection

```
{% assign pageTagsNumber = page.tags | size %}
{% assign related        = "" | split: "/" %}<!-- create empty array -->
{% assign relatedCount   = 0 %}
{% assign maxRelated     = 4 %}<!-- maximum number of related items -->
{% assign minTagMatch    = 4 %}<!-- minimum number of tag match to be a related -->
{% if minTagMatch > pageTagsNumber %}
    {% assign minTagMatch = pageTagsNumber %}
{% endif %}
{% assign matchedComplete = false %}<!-- flag -->

<!--
numberOfTag to match to be in the related list
Will try to match all page tags, then page tags size - 1, -2, until reaching minTagMatch
-->
{% for numberOfTag in (minTagMatch...pageTagsNumber) reversed %}

  <!-- Looping over site.posts or any site.mycollection -->
  <!-- here you can do {% for item in site.mycollection %} -->
  {% for item in site.posts %}
    <!-- !!! ITEM SPECIFIC -->
    <!-- for a collection change item.title == page.title if needed-->
    {% if related contains item or item.title == page.title %}
        <!--
        Don't scan an item that is already in related
        Don't scan an item if we are on his page
        -->
        {% continue %}<!-- go to next item -->
    {% endif %}
    {% assign itemTagsNumber = item.tags | size %}
    {% if itemTagsNumber < numberOfTag %}
      <!-- Not enough tags {{ itemTagsNumber }} -->
      {% continue %}<!-- go to next item -->
    {% endif %}
    {% assign matchingTags = 0 %}<!-- tag match counter -->
    {% for tag in page.tags %}
      <!-- Comparing page tag "{{ tag }}" to {{ item.tags | join: ", " }} -->
      {% if item.tags contains tag %}
        <!-- one matching tag increment matchingTags counter-->
        {% assign matchingTags = matchingTags | plus: 1 %}

        <!-- We have a match and {{ matchingTags }} matching tags total -->
        {% if matchingTags >= numberOfTag %}
            <!-- we have enough matching tag, this is a related item -->
            {% capture html %}
            <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">
            {{ item.title }}
            {% assign pageTagsNumber = item.tags | size %}
             - has {{ pageTagsNumber }} tags
             - match on {{ matchingTags }} tags
            </a></li>
            {% endcapture %}
            {% assign related = related | push: html %}
            {% assign relatedCount = related | size %}
            {% if relatedCount >= maxRelated %}
                <!-- if we have all our related set the matchedComplete flag to true -->
                {% assign matchedComplete = true %}
            {% endif %}
            {% break %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if matchedComplete == true %}
        <!-- matchedComplete breaking item loop! -->
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if matchedComplete == true %}
      <!-- matchedComplete breaking numberOfTag loop! -->
      {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if relatedCount > 0 %}

<!-- print related items -->
<ul>
  {% for item in related %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Amazing Liquid logic by the way, thanks! Anyway it seems to be broken, Jekyll 3.0.0 complies about "'for' tag was never closed", I'll check for its syntax, even though I'm just including it...

Comment: You certainly have a copied it wrong. Find the raw template here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djacquel/jekyllBoilerplate/gh-pages/_layouts/post.html

Comment: Hey @David Jacquel. Indeed its was a copy/paste mismatch. Anyway your syntax only works for me if I explicit assign "item" for my portfolio collection, so instead of  `{% for item in site.posts %} I had to change it to  `{% for item in site.portfolio %}. Any clues about why it is not matching with my collections tag? Thanks in advance, I'll vote it up as long as it works as intended.  Here's a screenshot of the result I'm getting https://cldup.com/0huSL_VgOE.png

Comment: I don't understand "not matching with collection tags" on your results image I can see that you have related projects with tag matchs

Comment: Oh man, never mind, I'm just starting with Jekyll, you're absolutely right, that's I who's confusing things around here. Thanks again for your help, I've learnt a bit more about Liquid with your syntax.

Comment: Hi! I'm still wrapping my head around Jekyll and found this (which is the closest I've come to finding code for what I want to do with the site I'm working on). However, I get the "'for' tag was never closed" error and I've triple checked I've copy & pasted all the code above.

The raw.githubusercontent url no longer works so I wondered if there was any chance I could have an explanation as to why it the code above may throw this error? I've tried changing the 'for item in site.posts' to match my collection but that doesn't seem like it would fix it anyway.